# Conditional keymap

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

Is it possible to map a key (e.g.: <kbd>Alt h</kbd>) to `_` (to go to the first character in the line), but to `|`, when already there? Perhaps in nvim/lua?

What I have tried is:

```lua
vim.keymap.set({'v', 'n'},   '<A-h>', function()
    if vim.o.wrap== true then
        return "g<Home>"
      else
        return "|"
    end
  end, {expr= true, desc= "goto first character on screen line"})
```

but I could not find out how to deal with the current cursor position.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I was hoping that there is a key for that which I missed, because this seems to be pretty natural movement.

Comment: Relevant, not exactly duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/35057/10604

Comment: Hoping for something is not really "trying". Yes what you ask is possible and you must try to solve your problem first if you want your question to attract attention.

Comment: Since when does attention depend on « trying to solve the problem »? Effort _asking_ a good question is certainly appreciated, and you could choose not to answer a question @romainl, but demanding that the querent do more than ask the query to garner your attention seems rude. You choose how to spend your time. Askers will put different levels of effort into their problems and question. I recommend suggesting improvements to the question, or not engaging if it’s not a question you would like to answer.

Comment: Since well before your first line of code and you liking it or not is of no importance. Suggesting an improvement is exactly what I did, OP delivered, and OP consequently got an answer. I'm doing your job, here, because you don't. Get a grip… starting by obeying your own rules about comments.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons?

Comment: I did some tests with your help, thank you indeed for your efforts. The intended cycling should be '0', '_', '|', dependent on where the cursor is in the (screen)line. I did not achieve this yet… For the reverse movement with <A-l>, say, it is '0', '$', 'g\_'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve with `|`. In particular how it is different from `0` in your context?

Comment: Writing LaTeX in nvim, I have long lines. A line may have (wrap over) several screenlines, intended by tabs. 0 moves to the first character on the screenline (after the tab), _ to the first character of the line, and | to the first character overall. They are all different.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with, finally, with your help:

```lua
vim.keymap.set({'n', 'v'},   '<A-h>', function()
    local col = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2]
    vim.cmd("normal g^")
    if col == vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2] then
      vim.cmd("normal _")
      if col == vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2] then
        vim.cmd("normal |")
      end
    end
  end, {desc= "goto last character on (screen) line"})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the column index you can do:

```
local col = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2]
```

Or in your mapping:

```lua
vim.keymap.set({'v', 'n'},   '<A-h>', function()
    if vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2] ~= 0 then
        return "g<Home>"
      else
        return "|"
    end
  end, {expr= true, desc= "goto first character on screen line"})
```